# Can't pause a thread in conjunction with third party library

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a problem with a closed source third party library and pausing a thread: I just can't pause a thread when using this third party library.

The OS is Ubuntu 32bit. Compiler is g++.

The next code below is trivial and works fine.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::chrono::seconds duration(3);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(duration);
}
```

I've compiled it with:

```
g++ -std=c++0x test1.cpp -o test1
```

Ok, now there is this third party library ("PvApi" for GigE Vision Devices from AVT) and my following code.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <PvApi.h>

int main()
{
  PvInitialize();

  std::chrono::seconds duration(3);
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(duration);
}
```

I've compiled it with:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -D_x86 -D_LINUX -D_REENTRANT test2.cpp -lPvAPI -o test2
```

When running the code it really runs! It just doesn't pause a nanosecond. Why???

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: What happens if you compile the first code with exact same flags as the second code? Does it still "run as expected" and pauses for 3 seconds?

When you try make sure you use exact same flags, to the point of including an (unneeded for the first code) library PvAPI

Answer (score 1):

This might be too late to help, but here's the deal: PvInitialize() apparently runs a timer_create() behind the scenes, and this generates frequent SIGALRM that interrupts the sleep() (or usleep(), both of which are really calling nanosleep()).  The only work-around that I am aware of is to use nanosleep() (which is what AVT's example codes use).  If you look at the man page for nanosleep(), it takes two arguments, both pointer to a timespec struct.  What happens is that when the sleep is interrupted, the second timespec contains the time left (i.e., how much more time it was suppose to sleep).  The following code segment is lifted from AVT's sample code:

/* time is in milliseconds */

void Sleep(unsigned int time)
{
        struct timespec t,r;

```
    t.tv_sec    = time / 1000;
    t.tv_nsec   = (time % 1000) * 1000000;

    while(nanosleep(&t,&r)==-1)
            t = r;
```

}

You can use this in place of all sleeps(), and it should take care of the majority of your problems, but watch out for other libraries that might not guard against this.  The other place you want to take care of is select() calls.

Comment: One other tidbit of information that might be of interest: if you try to start multiple threads, it appears that the PvInitialize() SIGALRM only hits the main thread, but not the child threads, **regardless of whether you invoke PvInitialize() inside or outside of the main thread**.  (I've only tried this on Linux however.)

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible that PvInitialize handle any signal sending by the OS?, which would stop sleeping of your process.

Comment: The only thing I know about PvInitialize() is, that it works asynchronous as the docs told me. I think that means threading.

Comment: So PvInitialise is the problem!, but without the documentation of this function I can't say anything more.

Comment: Here is the link: http://www.alliedvisiontec.com/fileadmin/content/PDF/Software/Prosilica_software/Prosilica_software_doc/PvAPI_SDK_Manual.pdf Site 59 is the interesting part. Other docs are not available.

Comment: Are you check if PvCameraCount() doesn't return 0? before continue your program.

Comment: If not you should do this before continue!

Comment: That's not an answer, but a guess

Comment: PvCameraCount() is used after calling PvInitialization(). But before  PvCameraCount() I need a pause.

Comment: PvCameraCount() is used after calling PvInitialization(). It's PvInitialization() what makes the problem. PvInitializationNoDiscovery() works fine as it is asynchronous. But it's PvInitialization() what I need.